# Select tag in TD

Tags: javascript, dom

I have select tag within a cell in the table. I want to add a new row only if the option is selected in the previous rows. I just want to know how to achieve it using DOM.

This is my addRow javascript function

```
  function addRow()
  {
   var newRow = document.all("estTable").insertRow();
   var tblObj = document.getElementById("estTable");

   var noOfRow = document.getElementById("estTable").rows.length;


   var oCell = newRow.insertCell();
   oCell.innerHTML = tblObj.rows[1].cells[0].innerHTML;
   oCell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex =0;

   oCell = newRow.insertCell();
   oCell.innerHTML = tblObj.rows[1].cells[1].innerHTML;
   oCell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex =0;

   oCell = newRow.insertCell();
   oCell.innerHTML = tblObj.rows[1].cells[2].innerHTML;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your new code would use:

```
var objParent = document.getElementById("someUniqueId");
```

Where `someUniqueId` is the row you want to get the parent of.  From here you can access the parent anyway you want to.